# observeEvent is triggered unnecessary when using one evenExpr for mulitple handlerExpr in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Im creating shiny app. for calculating risk score where the user will upload input file and select the input such as ethnic groups, type of calculating score and diseases. After all of the input are selected and file is uploaded, **my App. will be run when user click at action button** and the output such as graph and dataframe will be shown

Im using  **observeEvent** to control my App for triggering unnecessarily( **mulitple handleExpr with one eventExpr**), and this is my shorten version of code. Im sorry for my code that is not reproducible.

```
 observeEvent(input$action,{

    isolate(system2("bash_script/plink.sh",args = c(input$file$datapath,input$type,input$sum_stat,input$Disease,input$Ethnic,input$Ref)))

    output$table_score <- renderDataTable({
      percentile <- read.csv("../output/score_percentile.csv",header = T, sep = "\t")
    }, selection = "single")

    output$table_variant <- renderDataTable({
      varaints_in_sample <- fread("../output/summary.csv", header = T, drop = 1)
    })

    #Plot Graph
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      s <- input$table_score_cell_clicked
      plot("../output/score_percentile_plot.csv",s,"analysis")
    })

  })
```

**my problem is that** when Im running app for the first time, everything is controllable. **However**, if I want to select new input. for example im changing input disease from heart disease to another disease. my App. will be triggered unnecessarily although I did **NOT** click at action button.

So, Is there any way to use **observeEvent** with one evenExpr for mulitple handleExpr

Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: Could you please edit your code to show a fully reproducible example of your problem? It would be easier to help you and give you the most correct answer

Answer (score -1):

I think, this is simplified example of your problem. The solution is to put all your `input$...` inside `isolate()`.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         sliderInput("bins",
                     "Number of bins:",
                     min = 1,
                     max = 50,
                     value = 30),
         actionButton('action', 'Click')
      ),

      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        req(input$action)
        # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
        x    <- faithful[, 2] 
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = isolate(input$bins) + 1)

        # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: The `renderPlot()` should not be placed inside the button observer. If you want to trigger the plot to get drawn when the button is pressed, then you can just add `input$action` inside the `renderPlot()` function as its own line

Comment: Thanks !!! it work perfectly. So can i ask something more?. How can I prevent error like  **no such file in directory** of reading local file such as csv generated by the input inside isolate because it will show an error when starting App because it needs output from isolate first. I try to fix this by putting render* in observeEvent as my code show above and it works. But as @Dean mentions it should not put inside the button observer. Is there any way to deal with this issue. Thanks :)

Comment: Edited as per @DeanAttali comment. @Jolene try to put that input in `req()` that will not execute while it is not exist.